# Visualization of multiple Markov models

Tags: python, r, visualization, markov-process, simulation

I am working on a project where we compare over 10 different Markov models, each representing a different treatment plan.

Most often single models are visualized with a decision tree or [transition state diagram](http://guizzetti.ca/blogs/lenny/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/3state_markov.jpg). However, with multiple different models what are potential visualizations that could communicate the transition states that differentiate each model?

I have seen other people use a [table](http://www.bmj.com/highwire/markup/587855/expansion?width=1000&height=500&iframe=true&postprocessors=highwire_figures%2Chighwire_math) to depict different models and the transition states.

For clarity, I am not referring to a transition probabilities chart but a method of communicating the differences between multiple models.

Comment: Some attempts by neuroscientists: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/nath/docs/brainvis_chi2013.pdf.

Comment: The different models have different state spaces, I suppose?

Comment: That's correct. The models have different health states. The pattern is similar but I would like to highlight the differences.

Comment: You could represent the different models with different colors on the same generalized space. The figure could be interactive with the ability to select one or more models at a time.

Comment: How big are these? Number nodes? edges?

Comment: Check this out for customized graphs: https://github.com/atcemgil/notes/blob/master/DrawGraphs.ipynb

Comment: @AndrewBrown in case it is still relevant, can you please provide typical size of your models.

Answer (score 1):

If we limit the question on comparing two graphs, I can propose a way based on adjacency matrices comparison. There is a sample notebook: [graph_diff.ipynb](https://github.com/nchaly/mc_research/blob/master/etc/graph_diff.ipynb)

To summarize:

Having two graphs,

```
   A  B  C  D                  A  B  D  E  F
A  0  2  2  2               A  0  1  2  3  0
B  2  0  1  1               B  1  0  0  1  1
C  2  1  2  0               D  2  0  2  1  0
D  2  1  0  0               E  3  1  1  0  1
                            F  0  1  0  1  0
```

We can compare them and detect changes, producing result similar to `diff` output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
A  1  0 -2  1  2  2
B  0  1 -2 -2  2  2
C -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2
D  1 -2 -2  2  2  2
E  2  2 -2  2  2  2
F  2  2 -2  2  2  2
```

Compare matrix nodes from both graphs. Edges values indicate change:

- 1 = same edge
- 0 = changed edge
- -2 = removed edge
- +2 = added edge

This matrix can be visualized as grid:

[image]

Or as graph:

[image]

which is more informative because shows also nodes changes:

- green: new (added nodes E and F)
- red: removed (removed C)
- yellow: unaffected (A, B, D)

For simplicity, edges are unidirectional.